# gradle project sync completed with some errors in proxy

Tags: android, gradle

i am getting this error in my android studio please provide some solution to fix this i also tried various source from internet but problem still same actually i am using proxy below is my all screenshots

build.gradle Code

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.programmingwithbasics.myfirstapp"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    androidTestCompile files('libs/junit-4.12.jar')
}
```

[android studio error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ez8w.png)

Comment: please check gradle installed or not.

Answer (score 0):

Please check gradle installed or not.
It's download from internet automatically. apx. 66MB

```
C:\Users\UserName\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.14.1-all
```

If not work restart your android studio and check internet connectivity. 
Some time gradle error comes in new installed android studio. bcoz gradle is required and others cache files `.AndroidStudio2.2` stored in this folder.

Comment: you can download junit jar files from github and add in libs 

https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/releases/download/r4.12/junit-4.12.jar

Comment: i think gradle is not install cause C:\Users\Username\.gradle Path exist .but inside .gradle there are no Wrapper folder exist there are only three folder -> caches , daemon and native now tell me next step

Comment: "wrapper\ dists\ gradle-2.14.1-all" is required in .gradle folder

Comment: Close android studio and delete `.gradle` folder and rerun it.
it will regenerate folder and gradle download automatically internet is required.

Comment: i also download and unzip gradle-2.14.1 all now how to setup

Comment: Bro i tried what you said i tried  but same problem occuring again and again check you mail